# Unable to save variable(s) from a custom form

Tags: 6, forms, configuration

I want to create a custom form with a few textfields and then use `variable_set` to save those textfields as variables.

I am not able to save the variable with the code below.

Question: I do not see the drupal message on hitting submit and when I go to the 'variables' table, I do not see the variable 'id_event'. I have tried clearing all caches several times.

Code below is from *.module file of my custom module "mymodule"

```
    function mymodule_menu() {

     $items['example_form'] = array(
         'title'        =>  'Progress Numbers',
         'description'  =>  'Form to enter variables that will be shown on Progress Update Block on Front Page',
         'page callback'    => 'drupal_get_form',
         'page arguments'   => array('example_form_form1'),
         'access arguments' => array('access administration menu'),

     );

     return $items;
 }
```

The callback function:

```
 function example_form_form1($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['id_event'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Id Event'),
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#default_value' => variable_get('id_event', 7),
  );

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Submit'),
  );
  return $form;
}
```

Submit Function

```
function example_form_form1_submit(&$form, &$form_state) {
  variable_set('id_event', $form_state['values']['id_event']);
  drupal_set_message($id_event);
}
```

Comment: If you are using devel...then can you please dpm($form_state['values']['id_event']); & see whats it returning here in submit function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried the solution
and my result was excelent!

```
function felicitacion_mensaje_form($form, &$form_state) {
$form = array();
$form['felicitacion'] = array(
'#type' => 'textfield',
'#title' => t('Mensaje de felicitacion'),
'#default_value' => variable_get('congrat','Feliz cumpleaños !nombre te deseamos!.'),
'#description'   => t("Some description"),
);
return $form;
//   return system_settings_form($form);
}
function felicitacion_mensaje_form_submit(&$form, &$form_state) {
variable_set('congrat', $form_state['values']['felicitacion']);
$id_event = variable_get('congrat', '');
drupal_set_message($id_event);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Modify your example_form_form1_submit function as follows

```
function example_form_form1_submit(&$form, &$form_state) {
  variable_set('id_event', $form_state['values']['id_event']);
  $id_event = variable_get('id_event', '');
  drupal_set_message($id_event);
}
```

[image]

Comment: It was useful to me

Answer (score 0):

Drupal's variable API allows for storage of persistent variables across separate requests.

If you want to set a Drupal variable, you need to use [variable_set()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/variable_set/6).

Example:

```
$my_variable = 'very_important_value';          // Here we set a php variable

variable_set('my_variable_name', $my_variable); // Here we store the php variable
                                                // into a Drupal variable
```

If you want to retrieve the Drupal variable's value, you need to use [variable_get()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/variable_get/6).

```
$saved_value = variable_get('my_variable_name', 'default_value'); // Get the value of the
                                                                  // Drupal variable. If
                                                                  // it does not exist, then
                                                                  // use the second argument
```

You are seeing the value stored correctly in the database because you are making use of **variable_set()** correctly. However, when you are trying to retrieve the value, you need to be sure to call **variable_get()** to retrieve the value and store it into a php variable for further usage.

Suggestion:

```
function example_form_form1_submit(&$form, &$form_state) {

  variable_set('id_event', $form_state['values']['id_event']); // Stores the value

  $saved_value = variable_get('id_event', 'Default');          // Retrieve the stored value.
                                                               // If it is not saved,
                                                               // $saved_value will be set
                                                               // to 'Default'.
  drupal_set_message($saved_value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem using "system_settings_form($form);" since the solutions above did not work for me. (Will try later and if it works, will post any learnings here).

Following is what worked for me for reference:

My .module file:

```
function neil_menu() {

$items['admin/settings/neil'] = array(
    'title' => 'Node images',
    'description' => 'Control how to upload node images.',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('neil_admin_settings'),
    'access arguments' => array('administer site configuration'),
    'file' => 'neil.admin.inc',
);
 return $items;
```

}

neil.admin.inc file:

```
function neil_admin_settings() {
   $form['progress_so_far'] = array(
'#type' => 'textfield',
'#title' => t('Progress So Far'),
'#default_value' => variable_get('progress_so_far', '0'),
'#maxlength' => 255,
);

return system_settings_form($form);
}
```